# Set of unicode characters that do not have the same NFD and NFC encoding

Tags: unicode

What are the set of unicode characters that do not share the same NFC and NFD encoding?

For example 日本, in NFD and NFC are both u'\u65e5\u672c'

However のご賛同をいただき ました

in NFD: u'\u306e\u3053\u3099\u8cdb\u540c\u3092\u3044\u305f\u305f\u3099\u304d \u307e\u3057\u305f'

in NFC: u'\u306e\u3054\u8cdb\u540c\u3092\u3044\u305f\u3060\u304d \u307e\u3057\u305f'

(Definitions of NFD and NFC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization#Normal_forms)

Comment: I've added a Wikipedia link explaining what NFD and NFC are. Feel free to replace it with a better reference.

Answer (score 1):

NFC is performed by first decomposing a string, then recomposing some character sequences. So the set of single characters for which the result of NFC and NFD differs is every character which has a decomposition mapping in the UCD and is not [excluded from composition](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-18.html#Primary%20Exclusion%20List%20Table). These characters are also called [*primary composites*](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-18.html#D3).

Note that this only applies to single characters. If you're considering sequences of multiple characters, things get a lot more complicated. For example, a sequence of two characters for which the NFC and NFD forms are identical when applied separately can have different forms when applied to the entire sequence.

Comment: Is the exception you allude to in the second paragraph regarding re-ordering of combining characters?  Or are there other exceptions as well?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy The exception is regarding re-ordering *and composition* of combining characters.